# Absolute value of varchar from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have a field with value= **'''VALUE'''**.when i am selecting it return me **'VALUE'** with single quotes.
I want the **VALUE** in a varchar variable without quotes.how to achieve this without replace function.

THIS IS MY DYNAMIC QUERY WHICH IS IN THE TABLE

```
''''+'SELECT'+''''+'+'+''''''''''+'+ RTRIM(@start_Insert) +'+''' ''''+'''+'+ '+'''''''('''+' +  RTRIM(@Column_List_Insert) +'+'''''''+'''+'+' +''''''')''''''+'+
        ''' ''''+''+ ''''''(''+ RTRIM(@Column_List_Insert) + ''''''+''+'''''')''''''+'+
        ''' + '''' VALUES(''''+ '' +@Actual_Values_Insert+ ''+'''')''''''+'' ''+' +
        ''' FROM ''+ ''['' +RTRIM(@source) + '']''+ '+ 
        '''where (<col_name> BETWEEN ''''<col_value1>'''' AND ''''<col_value2>'''') AND <col_name3> <> ''''<col_value3>'''''''
```

Comment: `How to achieve that without replace.` Why?

Comment: actually i have a dynamic quary saved in table.so i can not perform replace simply

Comment: show your dynamic quary

Comment: Do you want to remove all single quotes, or just leading and trailing ones? What if two or more (leading or trailing)?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `SUBSTRING()`, and removing the leading and trailing single apostrophes?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(field, 2, LEN(field)-2) FROM table
```

As @RahulTripathi alluded in his comment, I would prefer to just `REPLACE()` out the apostrophes:

```
SELECT REPLACE(field, '''', '') FROM table
```

Comment: thanks for replay.but i can not do it.I have a dynamic query as value.I cam not simply replace it

Comment: What about using `SUBSTRING` ?

Comment: @NguyễnHảiTriều You are correct, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen substring will just remove quotes which might corrupt the query